# How to manage page titles dynamically in Vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I build an application. I have a header with the title of my page. Currently, I use view-router to define my titles.

```
{
    path: '/events',
    name: 'events',
    component: Events,
    meta: {
        title: 'Liste des événements'
    }
}
```

And in my blade view, in my header.blade.php I'm doing this to display the title

```
 <h2 class="header__title title-header">
    @{{ $route.meta.title }}
 </h2>
```

It work BUT when I have a dynamic data, necessarily, it does not work. For example, when I post a post, how can I do to earn my title?

```
    {
    path: '/events/:id',
    component: Event,
    name: 'Event',
    meta: {
        title: 'my dynamic title',
        page: 'event',
    },
```

How to recover the title of the post page? I have the name of the post in my post, but I can not access it from my header ...

[image]

I do not have access to the other components. These are components coming from element-ui.

Thank you in advance

Comment: usually i use data after fetch or post to set title, give it a try

Comment: @Sadeghbayan any example?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your router, before `export default router` you can add

```
router.beforeEach((toRoute, fromRoute, next) => {
  window.document.title = toRoute.meta && toRoute.meta.title ? toRoute.meta.title : 'Home';

  next();
})
```

This will read the meta title if it exists and it will update the page title.

Or you can add it like this

```
const router = new Router({
  beforeEach(toRoute, fromRoute, next) {
    window.document.title = toRoute.meta && toRoute.meta.title ? toRoute.meta.title : 'Home';

    next();
  },
  routes: [
    ...
  ]
})
```

Don't forget to change the default title value from `Home` to something else - maybe name of your project

Comment: Thanks @ljubadr, it work like a charm. But how can I do with the data of a post for example, when I visit the page of an article ? Thanks

Comment: After your ajax call to fetch the post finishes, you need to grab the tile of the article and set `window.document.title = response.data.title`. Can you provide code for your ajax call to fetch post and which post field should be set as title?